# FINDSTR Command Ignoring Regex

Tags: regex, windows, findstr

I'm searching for urls in a html file using the following in command prompt

`findstr /r "//i\.4cdn\.org/pol/\d+\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|webm|gif)" pol.html`

The regex works fine in a Notepad++ search, however when I run it with the `findstr` command it returns it's help page and this:

```
FINDSTR: // ignored
FINDSTR: /\ ignored
FINDSTR: /. ignored
FINDSTR: /4 ignored
FINDSTR: /c ignored
FINDSTR: /d ignored
FINDSTR: /\ ignored
FINDSTR: /. ignored
FINDSTR: /g ignored
FINDSTR: // ignored
FINDSTR: // ignored
FINDSTR: /\ ignored
FINDSTR: /d ignored
FINDSTR: /+ ignored
FINDSTR: /\ ignored
FINDSTR: /. ignored
FINDSTR: /( ignored
```

I'm pretty new to regex so if there's something wrong in there, sorry in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, [see computing.net](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/how-to-advoid-error-findstr-ignored/20674.html). Possibly you need to escape a double forward slash:

> If you ever need to actually search for "//" with findstr, escape with backslashes "\/\/"

Also findstr seems to have a very basic regex implementation. See [supported metacharacters](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true).

- `\d` possibly no support for *shorthands* (use `[0-9]`)
- `+` and even seems no `+` *quantifier* is available, only `*` supported
- `(?:png|jpg|jpeg|webm|gif)` possibly no support for *groups* at all

Comment: When adding a link, it is good to add important part of that link in answer.

Comment: I've tried using the escape slashes as well as the windows escape character (^). It stopped the 'ignored' messages coming up, but now it's not returning anything. Could be that it's interpreting the characters literally, thus not finding anything to return.

Comment: It looks from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx as if this uses an extremely limited variety of regular expression syntax. Doesn't even seem to support normal grouping.

Comment: Doing some tests shows you only need to quote the *first* forward-slash. That stops it from treating the regexp as an argument.

Comment: @IamaTerribleProgrammer, patthoyts Yes, I also just tried. It seems very limited regex options indeed :/

Comment: Ultimately I just ended up using `findstr i.4cdn.org/pol/ pol.html`. Not as clean in my opinion but it gets the job done.